# route always not found laravel 9

Tags: laravel, routes

This is my route

```
Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class)->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/posts/drafts', [PostController::class, 'draft'])->middleware('auth');
Route::put('/posts/{id}/reject', [PostController::class, 'reject'])->middleware('auth');
Route::put('/posts/{id}/publish', [PostController::class, 'publish'])->middleware('auth');
```

when i access `/posts/drafts` it's always not found, but when i disable the route resource, it can.

it's doesn't happen with `/posts/{id}/reject` and `/posts/{id}/publish`.

what is the solution ?

i tried to search in google but i confused.

i expect it gonna work and i understand why this happen

Edit : SOLVED

Comment: Try moving the routes above resource routes. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: Sachin Bahukhandi  thank you. its work

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if in case it helps. Posting the answer for anyone who comes across the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck on this problem,

Try moving your custom/additional routes above the resource routes:

```
Route::get('/posts/drafts', [PostController::class, 'draft'])->middleware('auth');
Route::put('/posts/{id}/reject', [PostController::class, 'reject'])->middleware('auth');
Route::put('/posts/{id}/publish', [PostController::class, 'publish'])->middleware('auth');

Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

This could also be wrapped as(Wrap the routes in a group):

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
   Route::get('/posts/drafts', [PostController::class, 'draft']);
   Route::put('/posts/{id}/reject', [PostController::class, 'reject']);
   Route::put('/posts/{id}/publish', [PostController::class, 'publish']);

   Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);
});
```

More Info here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: ``middleware('auth');`` is redundant for the resource route since it's already grouped with the auth middleware.

Comment: Thanks @OMiShah for pointing out. I missed it.